# VB.net Outlook checking for mail and calender events

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Hello all I have the following code that checks for currently unread messages:

```
 oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders(pair.Key)
 oItems = oInbox.Items
 oItems = oItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")

 Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
 For i As Integer = 1 To oItems.Count
    oMsg = oItems.Item(i)
    Dim tmpString As String = ""
    tmpString = oMsg.Subject & "^" & oMsg.SenderName & "^" & oMsg.ReceivedTime & "^" & oMsg.Body & "^" & oMsg.EntryID
    outlookFoldersMail.Add(dictionaryNum, tmpString)
    oMsg = Nothing
    dictionaryNum += 1
 Next
```

Now this works just fine with just emails but it seems to crash on the line **oMsg = oItems.Item(i)** when its trying to process a calender invite email.

The error is this:

*Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).*

What would I need to add/and or check in order for it not to crash if its a calender event invite?

**Code Update**

oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders(pair.Key)
     oItems = oInbox.Items
     oItems = oItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")

```
 Dim oMsg As Object

 For i As Integer = 1 To oItems.Count
    Debug.Print(oItems.Class)
    oMsg = oItems.Item(i)
    Dim tmpString As String = ""
    tmpString = oMsg.Subject & "^" & oMsg.SenderName & "^" & oMsg.ReceivedTime & "^" & oMsg.Body & "^" & oMsg.EntryID
    outlookFoldersMail.Add(dictionaryNum, tmpString)
    oMsg = Nothing
    dictionaryNum += 1
 Next
```

I no longer have an error on the **oMsg = oItems.Item(i)** but the **debug.print** output is **16** for both a normal email and calender invite....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring oMsg as Outlook.MailItem, but meeting requests are represented as Outlook.MeetingItem objects.

Declare oMsg as a generic Object and check the Class or MessageClass property at run-time to decide how to cast the current item.

Comment: You need to check oMsg.Class property, not oItems.Class.